# Problems with weblogic 9.2 load balancing and clustering using proxy plugin

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing

I have a cluster in weblogic 9.2 with 2 nodes(172.20.1.68:7101, 172.20.1.23:7102), 1 adminserver (172.20.1.23:7001) and 1 balancer (apache proxy plugin) 172.20.1.49:7103.

What I see in the balancer's access.log is that every request is marked as 404 not found. But in the node's log I can see those very same request distribuited marked as GET with code 200.

The problem is that my application is not working.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Edit:

Here it is my relevant httpd.conf, I have not section, instead I 
have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName fake.server.name  
        DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache_ssl/htdocs"  
        <Location /myApp/>  
             SetHandler weblogic-handler  
             WebLogicCluster 172.20.1.23:7102,172.20.1.68:7101  
             Debug All   
             DebugConfigInfo ALL  
             WLLogFile logs/p.log  
              KeepAliveEnabled ON  
             KeepAliveSecs 15  
        </Location>  

        <Location /psoc-app>
             SetHandler weblogic-handler
             WebLogicCluster 172.20.1.23:7102,172.20.1.68:7101
              KeepAliveEnabled ON
             KeepAliveSecs 15
        </Location>

    WLLogFile logs/p.log
    ErrorLog logs/_log_error
    CustomLog logs/_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

/tmp/wlproxy.log request:

```
================New Request: [GET /myApp/path HTTP/1.1] =================
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> INFO: SSL is not configured
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> Using Uri /myApp/path
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> After trimming path: '/myApp/path'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> The final request string is '/myApp/path'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> SEARCHING       id=[172.20.1.23:7102,172.20.1.68:7101] from current ID=[172.20.1.23:7102,172.20.1.68:7101]
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> The two ids matched
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> @@@FOUND...id=[172.20.1.23:7102,172.20.1.68:7101], server_name=[172.20.1.49], server_port=[80]
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> attempt #0 out of a max of 5
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> Trying a pooled connection for '172.20.1.68/7101/7106'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> getPooledConn: No more connections in the pool for Host[172.20.1.68] Port[7101] SecurePort[7106]
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> general list: trying connect to '172.20.1.68'/7101/7106 at line 2619 for '/myApp/path'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> INFO: New NON-SSL URL
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> Connect returns -1, and error no set to 115, msg 'Operation now in progress'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> EINPROGRESS in connect() - selecting
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> Local Port of the socket is 38958
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> Remote Host 172.20.1.68 Remote Port 7101
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> general list: created a new connection to '172.20.1.68'/7101 for '/myApp/path', Local port:38958
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> URL::parseHeaders: CompleteStatusLine set to [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> URL::parseHeaders: StatusLine set to [404 Not Found]
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> parsed all headers OK
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> sendResponse() : r->status = '404'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> canRecycle: conn=1 status=404 isKA=0 clen=1214 isCTE=0
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> closeConn: URL.canRecycle() returns false, deleting URL '172.20.1.68/7101'
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> request [/myApp/path] processed sucessfully..................
```

Sorry I just cant get the formatter to work

Comment: Are you using a web server (Apache) with proxy plugin? Are the cluster node access logs (with 200) showing the originating request IP address always as *172.20.1.23* i.e. that of the balancer server? This is to prove whether all requests are correctly fwded from plugin to node at all?

Comment: yes, I'm using Apache along with proxy plugin. In the cluster nodes access logs I see that the incoming connections are from the apache balancer. In the node log it says :  "GET /myApp/path HTTP/1.1" 200 0

And in the Apache access log I see: "GET /myApp/path HTTP/1.1" 404 1214

Thank you for your response!

Comment: Can you post the httpd.conf settings for *<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>*

Comment: Enable these flags on the plugin - Debug ON and set some WLLogFile  C:/proxydebug.log. You can see each request in DEBUG mode from Apache to Weblogic and see whats happening.

Comment: Okay DEBUG already enabled - can you track the request in logs/p.log ?

Comment: This is strange, I have no such logs/p.log, but I can paste /tmp/wlproxy.log a whole request in the question.

Comment: So where in the conf is it picking up /tmp/wlproxy.log from? suggests something is wrong config eh? ALSO is the space in this tag **(between < and L)** < Location /myApp/> a formating mistake or actually present in your conf?

Comment: Sorry about that space "< L...>" I don't quite get the formatter to work (getting better thou) and it just scaped it as a tag. My bad not to say it. That's a good question (about the config and wlproxy.log) go to see!

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to ping the WL from the Apache ? No connectivity errors? Apache gets a 404 as this line in log shows.
*Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> general list: created a new connection to '172.20.1.68'/7101 for '/myApp/path', Local port:38958
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> URL::parseHeaders: CompleteStatusLine set to [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments so far there are 3 things to note and try:

A) Where in the Apache conf is it pointing to  `/tmp/wlproxy.log` ? This questions whether we are looking at the right conf file - or is there perhaps another instance of Apache running?

Run this command (if on unix) to identify the owner pid writing into the log

```
/usr/sbin/fuser /tmp/wlproxy.log
```

This will return the pid of an Apache process - is that the Apache which you are running?

You could also try running fuser with your Apache shut down and see does it still show a pid owning the file?

B) The plugin debug log shows the apache request goes to the 2nd server in the cluster and gets a 404.

```
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> general list: created a new connection to '172.20.1.68'/7101 for '/myApp/path', Local port:38958 
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> URL::parseHeaders: CompleteStatusLine set to [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found] 
Thu Jul 29 14:30:00 2010 <1382912804066002> URL::parseHeaders: StatusLine set to [404 Not Found]
```

Is the application definitely deployed and available on `172.20.1.68:7101/myApp/path` also ?

C) What happens when you make a request for the `/psoc-app` shown in the conf?

Comment: Thank you for your time. The file /tmp/wlproxy.log is the default log file. I solved it, the problem was that in weblogic the application had an error when deploying (it is on a multinode cluster).

Thank you again for your answers and time!